# react hooks setState does not properly re-render component

Tags: material-ui, react-hooks

I have a component(toggle Menu List) that is supposed to load a child component(toggle Menu Items) on button click.

Here is How it works.

'btnId' init state = null

-> button click

-> update state to index number 1

-> (btnId !== null) && load the child component

However the child component is not being displayed on state update.

If I set init state to 1, it is displayed on button click.

### toggleMenuList.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
/* --- Components --- */
import Loader from '../../shared/loader';

const ToggleMenuItems = Loader({
  loader: () =>
    import('./toggleMenuItems' /* webpackChunkName: 'ToggleMenuItems' */),
});

const styles = theme => ({
...
});

const ToggleMenuList = ({ navAdminList, navAdminItems, classes }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [btnId, setBtnId] = useState(null);
  const anchorRef = useRef(null);

  const handleToggle = async id => {
    await setBtnId(id);
    return setOpen(prevOpen => !prevOpen);
  };

  const handleClose = event => {
   ...
  };

  console.log('Toggle Menu List is rendered');
  console.log('btnId: ', btnId);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={`nav-menu ${classes.root}`}>
        {navAdminList.map(e => (
          <Button
            key={e.id}
            ref={anchorRef}
            aria-owns={open ? 'menu-list-grow' : undefined}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            onClick={() => handleToggle(e.id)}
            className={e.className}
          >
            {e.name}
          </Button>
        ))}
      </div>
      {btnId !== null && (
        <ToggleMenuItems
          handleClose={handleClose}
          open={open}
          anchorRef={anchorRef}
          items={navAdminItems[btnId]}
        />
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ToggleMenuList);
```

### toggleMenuItems.js

```
const ToggleMenuItems = ({ handleClose, open, anchorRef, items }) => {

  console.log('Toggle Menu Items is rendered.');
  console.log('open: ', open);

  return (
    <Popper
      open={open}
      anchorEl={anchorRef.current}
      keepMounted
      transition
      disablePortal
    >
      {({ TransitionProps, placement }) => (
        <Grow
          {...TransitionProps}
          style={{
            transformOrigin:
              placement === 'bottom' ? 'center top' : 'center bottom',
          }}
        >
          <Paper id="menu-list-grow">
            <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
              <MenuList>
                {items.map(e => (
                  <MenuItem key={e.id} onClick={handleClose}>
                    <Link to={e.to} className={e.className}>
                      {e.name}
                    </Link>
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </MenuList>
            </ClickAwayListener>
          </Paper>
        </Grow>
      )}
    </Popper>
  );
};

export default ToggleMenuItems;
```

**Here is console logs i gets.**

```
* On page load
toggleMenuList.js:  Toggle Menu List is rendered
toggleMenuList.js:  btnId:  null

* On button click
toggleMenuList.js:  Toggle Menu List is rendered
toggleMenuList.js:  btnId:  1
toggleMenuList.js:  Toggle Menu List is rendered
toggleMenuList.js:  btnId:  1

toggleMenuItems.js: Toggle Menu Items is rendered.
toggleMenuItems.js: open: true
```

**result**

- The state value is updated.
- The child component seems to be loaded. (console.log gets fired)
- But It is not displayed.

Comment: Can you make a minimal funcional example on CodeSandbox?

Comment: I resolved the problem. Thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem with a different approach. I set activeId state with initial value 'null' which updates with 'clicked button id' on button click. And load the child component only when 'button Id' matches 'activeId'.

And I also add this condition in child component.

```
const isOpen = activeId === id;

  return (
    <Popper
      open={isOpen}
```

This way, when one button's open is true, the rest is set to false.

### toggleMenuList.js

```
const ToggleMenuList = ({ navAdminList, navAdminItems, classes }) => {
  const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(null);
  const anchorRef = useRef(null);
  const handleToggle = id => {
    setActiveId(id);
  };
  const handleClose = (event) => {
    if (anchorRef.current && anchorRef.current.include(event.target)) {
      return;
    }
    setActiveId(null);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={`nav-menu ${classes.root}`}>
        {navAdminList.map(e => (
          <div key={e.id}>
            <Button
              ref={anchorRef}
              aria-owns={activeId === e.id ? 'menu-list-grow' : undefined}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={() => handleToggle(e.id)}
              className={e.className}
            >
              {e.name}
            </Button>
            {activeId === e.id && (
              <ToggleMenuItems
                id={e.id}
                activeId={activeId}
                handleClose={handleClose}
                anchorRef={anchorRef}
                items={navAdminItems[e.id]}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

### toggleMenuItems.js

```
const ToggleMenuItems = ({ id, activeId, handleClose, anchorRef, items }) => {
  const isOpen = activeId === id;

  return (
    <Popper
      open={isOpen}
      anchorEl={anchorRef.current}
      keepMounted
      transition
      disablePortal
    >
      {({ TransitionProps, placement }) => (
        <Grow
          {...TransitionProps}
          style={{
            transformOrigin:
              placement === 'bottom' ? 'center top' : 'center bottom',
          }}
        >
          <Paper id="menu-list-grow">
            <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => handleClose(id)}>
              <MenuList>
                {items.map(e => (
                  <MenuItem key={e.id} onClick={() => handleClose(id)}>
                    <Link to={e.to} className={e.className}>
                      {e.name}
                    </Link>
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </MenuList>
            </ClickAwayListener>
          </Paper>
        </Grow>
      )}
    </Popper>
  );
};
```